# Не отображается прогресс бар пр использовании QProgressDialog

Tags: c++, qt

Нужен бесконечный прогресс-бар, делаю так:

```
 QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWi m;
  m.setWindowTitle("Управление");
  m.show();

  QProgressDialog *progressDialog = new QProgressDialog(&m);
  progressDialog->setLabelText("Подготовка системы к работе...");
  progressDialog->setRange(0, 0);
  progressDialog->setModal(true);
  progressDialog->show();
  app.processEvents();
  //сигнал по завершению cleanComputeFolder()
  QObject::connect(&m, SIGNAL(loadingSystemStop()), 
                   progressDialog, SLOT(close()));
  m.cleanComputeFolder();

  return app.exec();
```

Результат на скрине: появляется виджет, но ни текста, ни прогресс бара не отображается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как минимум, QCoreApplication::processEvents(); нужно запускать в цикле.

Comment: вы правы, моя запись неверна. Исправила на QCoreApplication::processEvents()  , теперь видно текст и полосу прогресса, но при этом они выглядят зависшими (нельзя тыкать, прогресс просто пустой и неподвижный, курсор в виде бублика с бесконечной загрузкой). При этом сама прога не висит и все делает, закрывает диалог прогресса по сигналу как положено

Comment: если выглядит зависшим, значит не обрабатывает отрисовку.

Comment: Добавила QCoreApplication::processEvents() в недры проги, в цикл. Заработало. Хотя это конечно как-то коряво))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавила QCoreApplication::processEvents() в недры проги, в цикл. Заработало.